# Problems with splitting source file which contains unexpected characters and inconsistent format

Tags: c#, csv, split

I have the following txt file which contains the "|" separator. I want to read the file and output it in a csv file.

```
Date|Currency|Location|Company|Price 
11112012|GBP|London|EasyJet|200.00
12122012|GBP|Manchester|British|Airways|100.00
10102014|EUR|Frankfurt|Lufthansa|300.00
10102014|EUR|Paris|Air|France|500.00
```

However as you can see from the 3rd and 5th row, the format is inconsistent. The user has added an additional "|" for company name. How can I write C# script that would copy the above into a csv file which would produce the below result. The bit I am struggling with are rows 3 and 5.

```
Date     Currency Location   Company          Price 
11112012 GBP      London     EasyJet          200.00
12122012 GBP      Manchester British Airways  100.00
10102014 EUR      Frankfurt  Lufthansa        300.00
10102014 EUR      Paris      Air France       500.00
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: If there are five pipes, eliminate the fourth one (that is, if that is the only anomaly in formatting; if there is more weirdness, more kludgery would be afoot).

Comment: Then keep replacing pipes with spaces, backwards from the penultimate pipe (inclusive).

Answer (score 1):

First, cleanse the data. Pseudocode:

```
List<String> cleansedFile = new List<String>();
int pipeCount;
foreach (String line in textFile)
{
    pipeCount = // count how many pipes are in the line
    if (pipeCount == 5)
    {
        String s = // replace fourth pipe with a space
    }
    cleansedFile.Add(s);
}
cleansedFile.SaveToFile("cleanFile.txt");
```

Then you can proceed as desired (with consistent/reliable lines).

Again, this is providing there are always four or five pipes; if there are sometimes more or less, that would complicate matters a little.

### UPDATE

Perhaps a better way would be to split the lines on the pipe into an array, so that you would have arrays like:

```
[0] = 11112012
[1] = GBP // Green Bay Packers, I take it
[2] = London
[3] = EasyJet
[4] = 200.00

[0] = 12122012
[1] = GBP
[2] = Manchester
[3] = British
[4] = Airways
[5] = 100.00
```

You could then recombine the values, concatenating elements 3 and 4 if there were 6 elements instead of 5; similar gyrations could be made for other scenarios.

Comment: I don't think this will work. What would happen with a city like Rio?

Comment: See my comment to your other comment; and my caveat above. I'm just answering the question as written.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a regular expression; e.g.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] data = new string[]{"Date|Currency|Location|Company|Price","11112012|GBP|London|EasyJet|200.00","12122012|GBP|Manchester|British|Airways|100.00","10102014|EUR|Frankfurt|Lufthansa|300.00","10102014|EUR|Paris|Air|France|500.00"};
        Regex splitter = new Regex("([^|]+)|([^|]+)|([^|]+)|(.+)|([^|]+)");

        int lineNo = 0;
        foreach (var line in data)
        {
            lineNo++;
            int fieldNo = 0;
            foreach (var value in splitter.Matches(line))
            {
                fieldNo++;
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Line {0:00} Column: {1:00}: Value: {2}", lineNo, fieldNo, value.ToString()));
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```